Proving, if $f$ is a decreasing function and $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x $ exists then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0 $?
The function of the question is defined as $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R $ and $f(x)\geq0 $ for every $x\geq0 $. The function is also monotonously decreasing. I'm asked to prove or disprove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=0 $ given the fact that  $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x $ exists.
Proof attempt
Since $f(x)\geq0 $ for every $x\geq0 $ we can conclude that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  \geq0 $. If $n\in\mathbb N $ we get $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  \ \geq \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  \ \geq0 $. We get $\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  \ \leq\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  $. Since $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  $ converges it implies that $\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  $ also converges.
Consider $g_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  \ $. Since $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x  \ =S $ , where $S\in\mathbb R $ then if we differentiate we get $(\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x )'=0 $.
$g_n(x) $ is differentiable so $(g_n(x))'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\cdot0=0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\cdot(\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)-f(0) $. Now if $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=0 $ we get $(g_n(x))'=-f(0)\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} $ which is $+\infty $ or $-\infty $ , contradiction.
I'm sure I did something wrong. Thanks in advance!

My intuition, FWIW, would be if $\inf g(x)=k$ exists then $g(x)\ge k$ and so $\int_a^b g(x)dx \ge \int_a^b k\ dx= k[b-a]$ (and if $b=\infty$ then $\int_a^\infty k\ dx=\infty$).  Thus a proof by contradiction could be in order.

"gn(x) is differentiable" Bear in mind $g_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1n S$ and is either a constant, or an infinite sum that does not converge.  (As $\sum \frac 1n$ is the harmonic series and does not converge $g_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1nS$. ... Actually come to think of it, you subscript of $g_{\color{red}n}(x)=\sum_{\color{blue}n=1}^\infty\frac 1{\color{blue}n}S$ doesn't make any sense as it refers to an index that spans all values with its own definition.

"if we differentiate we get (∫∞0f(x)dx)′=0."  That is true of all definite integers.  Note $\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac {x^3}3_{|0^3}=9$ and $(9)' = 0$. This is not to be confused with the antiderivative $\int{\text{no index}} x^3dx = \frac {x^3}3 + C$ and $(\frac {x^3}3 + C)' = x^2$.  Be careful that what you claim will apply to all functions.

Erk... meant to write $\int_0^{\color{red}3} x^2dx = \frac {x^3}3_{|_0^3}=9$.... Just in case that upper index of $1$ but evaluating at $3$ made my above comment confusing.

All in all the heart of why you argument fails is you are confusing a definite integral $\int_a^{b} f(x)dx = F(b)-F(c)=Constant$ (or a limit value which might or might not converge) with the antiderivative $\int f(x)dx = F(x)\pm C$.  It is true that $(\int f(x)dx)' = F'(x)=f(x)$ [to the extent such a statement can be valid] but it is NOT true that $(F(a)-F(b))' = f(a) -f(b)$.  As $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ are constants and are not functions $(F(a))'=0$ and $(F(a))'\ne F'(a)$.   In fact $f'(x){|{x=a}}$ is a completely different concept then $(f(a))'=(constant)' = 0$.

yes I figured it out now.

Your solution makes no sense as it contains several errors, plus a couple of unnecessary sentences. First of all, when it is said that $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ exists, it means $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx < \infty$. Put $S = \int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$, you always get $S \geqslant \frac{1}{n}S$ just for $S$ being a non-negative real number. Second, please check that your $g_n(x)$ actually does not depend neither on $x$ nor on $n$.
To solve the problem, choose $\epsilon > 0$ and sequence $x_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ with $f(x_n) \geqslant \epsilon$ for every $n$. Since $f$ is decreasing, we know in fact that $f(x) \geqslant \epsilon$ always holds and the integral cannot be finite.

I thought I messed everything up. got it!

First, note that if $f$ is decreasing then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists in the extended sense (as a matter of fact, since $f(x)\geq 0$, it is finite). Indeed, let $M=\inf_{x\in [0,\infty)}f(x)\geq 0$. Then given $\varepsilon>0$, by the definition of $\inf$ there exists some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)-\varepsilon\leq M<f(x_0)<f(x_0)+\varepsilon$. Now since $f$ is decreasing, for every $x>x_0$:
$$f(x)-\varepsilon\leq f(x_0)-\varepsilon< M< f(x)+\varepsilon$$
implying $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=M$.
Now if $M>0$, then for $\varepsilon=\frac{M}{2}>0$ there exists some $x_0$ such that for every $x\geq x_0$, $f(x)\geq\frac{M}{2}$. But then:
$$\int_{x_0}^\infty f(x)\geq\int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{M}{2}dx$$
and the RHS obviously diverges, contradicting the assumption.

The issue is that, once calculated, $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is just a constant. $g_n$ is not a function of $x$; the $x$ in the integral is a dummy variable, not a number you replace when plugging in other values.
In fact, a similar error occurs with $n$; $n$ is the running index of the sum, so $g$ does not depend on it either.
This result is most easily proved, in my opinion, by assuming the limit does not equal $0$ and deriving a contradiction. For instance, if $\lim f(x) = L \ne 0$, then
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \; \exists M > 0 \text{ such that } |f(x)-L| < \varepsilon
$$
Then $f(x) \in (L-\varepsilon,L+\varepsilon)$. Play around with that and the implications for $\int_M^\infty f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$; it's easily motivated geometrically (and in fact your result has more assumptions than it needs).
